# Automatically create recurring donations from bank statements

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions, civibanking

I'm using the wonderful civibanking extension to import the bank statments, including creating the contributions from the donors that directly wire money to our bank account

for the "normal" bank transfers (one off) it works great, we lookup the donor, create a new contribution and all is well

However, we have some donors that sends the same amount every month. They have a different transfer type (one of the column in the bank statement), so we can identify them.

Instead of "simply" creating a contribution, we'd like to 
1) check if there is an active recurring contribution of type "bank transfer", if not, create it
2) add the contribution as one linked with that recurring contribution

Is this possible to do out of the box? Any guidance on how to code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if Civirules does it(pretty sure it doesn't). Through an extension i would use pre hook to check and create contribution recur when a contribution is created. Here is small snippet

```
function extension_civicrm_pre($op, $objectName, $id, &$params) {
  if ($objectName == 'Contribution' && $op == 'create') {
    $bankTransferFinancialTypeId = civicrm_api3('FinancialType', 'getvalue', [
      'return' => "id",
      'name' => "Bank Transfer",
    ]);
    if ($bankTransferFinancialTypeId == $params['financial_type_id']) {
      // perform checks if contribution recur exists
      try {
        $recurringcontributionId = civicrm_api3('ContributionRecur', 'getvalue', [
          'return' => "id",
          'contact_id' => $params['contact_id'],
          'amount' => $params['total_amount'],
          'contribution_status_id' => ['IN' => ["Pending", "In Progress"]],
          'options' => ['limit' => 1],
        ]);
      }
      catch (CiviCRM_API3_Exception $e) {
        $recurringcontribution = civicrm_api3('ContributionRecur', 'create', [
          'contact_id' => $params['contact_id'],
          'installments' => '12',
          'frequency_interval' => '1',
          'amount' => $params['total_amount'],
          'contribution_status_id' => 'In Progress',
          'start_date' => date('YmdHis'),
          'currency' => 'USD',
          'frequency_unit' => 'month',
        ]);
        $recurringcontributionId = $recurringcontribution['id'];
      }
      $params['contribution_recur_id'] = $recurringcontributionId;
    }
  }
}
```

> Note: This snippet is not tested since i have just created it and is
>   pure blind coding.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks pradeep, I should have been clearer: the code itself wasn't the question, but more how to do it as one of the matcher/analyser plugins in civibanking. This being said, your idea of using a pre-hook is a nice workaround!